# UIImage name in xibs issue: should I use @2x

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimageview, uiimage

For instance I have image great_image.png and great_image@2x.png for retina display.
If I want to create UIImage in code I just write:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"great_image"];
```

But if I create UIImageView in xib and I want to set image in xib, I need to write image name.
What should I write: `"great_image.png" or "great_image@2x.png" or "great_image"` ? (because if I write "great_image", I will not see image in xib).

**Update:
the second part of question:**

What if I only have great_image@2x.png and don't have great_image.png, should I write great_image.png in xib anyway?

Comment: always use great_image.png .

Comment: No need to write but if you are using your image image in ios 4.3 or less it will take image of double resolution

Comment: pls anybody answer: What if I only have great_image@2x.png and don't have great_image.png, should I write great_image.png in xib anyway?

Comment: Please see above comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to set great_image.png in xib.Because it will take @2x image if it is in retina dispaly.
2. if you don't have great_image.png image in your project in that case it will not display in non-retina device

Comment: pls take a look at the update: What if I only have great_image@2x.png and don't have great_image.png, should I write great_image.png in xib anyway?

Comment: about "if you don't have great_image.png image in your project in that case it will not display in non-retina device". So if I don't have great_image.png and I need to support non-retina devices I need to write great_image@2x.png in xib ? (because as I understood in this case the image will appear on non-retina device but with poorer quality). correct?

Comment: No, If you don't have great_image.png in your project in that case you can't load @2x image in non-retina display.@2x image will be available only in retina display.

Comment: I tried, and I can see image on non-retina device, but I don't have great_image.png file and have great_image.png in xib

Comment: i seems you run your either retina device or you need to clear your xcode n reset your simulator. Because i'm preety sure great_image.png won't work in non-retina display.

Answer (score 1):

if you have great_image.png and great_image@2x.png in your project  then when you use

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"great_image"];
```

It will automatically load great_image.png if your screen scale is 1.0 (iPhone3G/3GS) or great_image.png if your screen scale is 2.0 (retina, iPhone 4).

no need to specify great_image@2x.png

if you have only @2x image 
The high resolution @2x images are not automatically down-sampled on non-retina devices.

Non-retina devices will however down-size and display the high resolution @2x images, but without down-samling them, so it will result in to poor quality..

Answer (score 0):

You can set the image property of imageview from xib. you just have to give the name of that image.if image is not displaying in image view then check your bundle resources that whether that image is added into in or not.
Secondly you dont have to specify @2x with image name because compiler decides at runtime by considering the device(non ratina or ratina).